# Excel 2013 - Look up data and highlight cells

Tags: excel

Sheet One - Performance Template (using Lookup)
Sheel Two - Raw Data for all 70 individuals
Sheet Three - Rota

Using Excel to manage performance data over year. Have used a Lookup command to use one performance  template sheet to display information for individual based on data compiled on a separate raw data sheet with all 70 individuals performance results on.

What I would like to do is use another sheet in the same workbook with a rota on, and for Excel to highlight the individuals shifts through formatting the cells, based on who's data is showing on the performance template.

Not sure how to achieve this and would be grateful if anyone could help please.

Comment: [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) with a native worksheet formula is an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your rota sheet you have all possible shifts listed. If you can use a visible (or hidden) cell relative to shift. Then you can compare the shift with a fixed cell on the template sheet that shows the shift pattern of the selected person. If they match then highlight. Voila

Comment: Thanks Mike. So simple and yet so effective.  